# I want to start new Activity when i click on ListView's content

Tags: android

```
ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

Intent i = new Intent(this, contents.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

But when i click on ListView it encounters en error. Tell me where i m wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>